# how can I found flutter text to speech and speech to text amharic language accenet

Tags: flutter, text-to-speech, speech-to-text

how can I set the assistant accent to native amharic speaker in flutter text-to-speech and speech to text?

```
Future _Speak() async {
    await _flutterTts.setLanguage('en-US');
    await _flutterTts.setVoice({"name": "Karen", "locale": "en-US"});
    await _flutterTts.setPitch(1.0);
    await _flutterTts.setVolume(1);
    await _flutterTts.setSpeechRate(0.5);
    // await _flutterTts.speak(_textController.text);
    if (_tts != null) {
      if (_tts!.isNotEmpty) {
        await _flutterTts.speak(_tts!);
      }
    }
  }
```

it really works with English accent (it can read Amharic alphabets but the accent is not good to listen for native Amharic speakers ), so what should I do?

I am trying to develop Amharic text to speech and speech to text converter

Answer (score 0):

To set the accent to native Amharic, you will need to set the language and voice parameters of the _flutterTts object to the appropriate values.

For the language parameter, you can use am-ET as the value to specify Amharic as the language.

For the voice parameter, you will need to find the specific voice that sounds like a native Amharic speaker. You can try using different values for the name and locale keys within the voice parameter to see which one produces the desired result.